# Datatable : Wrong column being sorted that get data from server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable that the data being rendered from the server. Here is the code in the client side:

> The issue is that when I'm sorting column #7, it is order next column #8. Which configuration is missed or is wrong here? **please check the image**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $table = $('#todo_table');
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var ajax_source =  '/admin/todos/list_datatable';
    var aoColumns = [
        {"mDataProp": "id", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true},
        {"mDataProp": "title", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true},
        {"mDataProp": "type", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false},
        {"mDataProp": "delivery_mode", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true},
        {"mDataProp": "reporter", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": true},
        {"mDataProp": "schedule", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true},
        {"mDataProp": "status", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": true},
        {"mDataProp": "date", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": true},
        {"mDataProp": "actions", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false}
    ];
    var settings = {
        "aoColumns": aoColumns,
        "aaSorting": (searchParams.get('my') == '1') ? [[6, "desc"]] : [[8, "desc"]],
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
            aoData.push({
                "name": "my",
                "value": (searchParams.get('my') == '1') ? true : false
            });
            oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "POST",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback
            });
        }
    };
    $table.ib_serverSideTable(ajax_source, settings);
```

[image]

Comment: It might be a good idea to show us your server side code too??

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $table = $('#todo_table');
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var ajax_source = '/admin/todos/list_datatable';
var aoColumns = [
    { "mDataProp": "id", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true },
    { "mDataProp": "title", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true },
    { "mDataProp": "type", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false },
    { "mDataProp": "delivery_mode", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true },
    { "mDataProp": "reporter", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": true },
    { "mDataProp": "schedule", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true },
    { "mDataProp": "status", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": true },
    { "mDataProp": "date", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": true },
    { "mDataProp": "actions", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false }
];
var settings = {
    "aoColumns": aoColumns,
    "aaSorting": (searchParams.get('my') == '1') ? [[6, "desc"], [7, "desc"]] : [[8, "desc"], [9, "desc"]],
    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
        aoData.push({
            "name": "my",
            "value": (searchParams.get('my') == '1') ? true : false
        });
        oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "POST",
            "url": sSource,
            "data": aoData,
            "success": fnCallback
        });
    }
};
$table.ib_serverSideTable(ajax_source, settings);
```

});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).